# C++ application autorun on windows boot

Tags: c++, windows, autorun

I am developing an application in C++ that has an option "autostart". When user set that option, program should change **something** in Windows to be started by Windows on next Windows boot and user logon. Also when user unset this option, the program must put things back.

I don't need to run app as a service, so it would enough to run under certain user's account after user logon. So what is the best way to make windows run my app. on next boot and user logon? I googled up an advice to use a startup folder. Is that most nice and harmless way?

If so, i have 2 questions:

1. How to detect startup folder. I am not happy with **SHGetSpecialFolderLocation()**'s output. It seems it returns my "HOME" directory in testing WinXP platform (C:\Documents and settings\%username%).
2. How to create .lnk file using C++ there? I think copying entire .exe file would be bad idea.

Actually my program is cross-platform, but an option "autostart" will be windows-only.

**Update**

1. Tried SHGetSpecialFolderLocation and got a good value in Windows7: "C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
   NOTICE: If you use MinGW, you should define _WIN32_IE to 0x0400, before including ShlObj.h.
2. What is the best solution (in point of view good programming) between using registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) and the startup folder?

Comment: For all users or just current logged on user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using registry keys like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Create a string value here with the name of your software and value of your main executable path - this should suffice. Much easier then creating a .lnk file - and registry editing API is easily accessible from C++

UPDATE:

As @Ben suggested, for your task it's better to use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. This will autostart your app for current user only, while my first suggestion will do this for all users.

UPDATE2:

Also note that whatever method you choose for implementing autostart, you might get problems with antivirus software as most of antiviruses with proactive defense are watching closely for making programs auto-running.

Comment: Better: Do it under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of `HKLM`.

Comment: @ben different meaning for sure but not better from all standpoints?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The question says it's an option to be set by the user.

Comment: @Ben there are plenty of people who aren't aware of standard user limitations on windows

Comment: @Ben: what is best solution between using the startup folder and the registry for my goal?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: All the more reason to suggest solutions which work under reduced privilege.

Comment: @Ben I just wanted to bring it to the attention of Pavel that there is an issue here that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @Pavel: I agree with Sergey and Norbert that the registry method is simpler, for both you and the user.  The startup folder is more for programs added to auto-start by the user, the registry is more for autoruns added automatically (although with the user's permission).  And there's no scarcity of tools to let the user see what programs are listed in the registry Run key.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the startup folder items happen at login time, NOT boot. That sounds like what you want, I just want to get the terms straight.

I think you actually want [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204.aspx), and the [CSIDL_STARTUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx) constant. If I'm reading the docs correctly that should give you the path you want.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the path to the startup folder using SHGetSpecialFolderPath (see Michael Kohne's answer).

Then use [IShellLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Shellink_Creating_Shortcut) in order to create a shortcut in this folder.

Edit: I think using the Run key in the registry is more reliable.